# android admob size on dimensions error: A 'type' attribute is required for <item>

Tags: android, styles, size, admob, dimensions

I have a layout and the attribute:

ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"

I want to put it with 
ads:adSize="@dim... dim name"

but it gives me error 
for example: FULL_BANNER
it says something like full banner doesn't exist and it doesn't compile.

I tried it now on styles but it doesn't work too:

```
<item name="ads:adSize">LEADERBOARD</item>
```

it says error: A 'type' attribute is required for

any idea?

Comment: You can achieve this programmatically or use via xml using the values in the res folder. See my answer. BTW, you should be using admob via the google play services library. You would have access to methods like adView#setAdSize(size), which would have made things easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically load the ad's size based on screen resolution, programatically.

In your activity's class onCreate():

```
        AdSize adSize = AdSize.SMART_BANNER;

        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        double density = dm.density * 160;
        double x = Math.pow(dm.widthPixels / density, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(dm.heightPixels / density, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x + y);

        if (screenInches > 8) { // > 728 X 90
            adSize = AdSize.IAB_LEADERBOARD;
        } else if (screenInches > 6) { // > 468 X 60
            adSize = AdSize.IAB_BANNER;
        } else { // > 320 X 50
            adSize = AdSize.BANNER;
        }

        LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_parent_layout);
        adView = new AdView(this, adsize, "xxxxxxxxxx");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Place the ad view.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        adContainer.addView(adView, params);
```

If you prefer defining the adview in xml format and referencing the values from the `values-sw600, values-sw720`.. folders you can define the width and height in `dimens.xml`:

**In values/dimens.xml**

```
  <resources>
        <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
        <dimen name="admob_width">320dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="admob_height">50dp</dimen>
    </resources>
```

**Then, in your layout:**

```
<com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/admob_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/admob_height"
    ads:adUnitId="your_unit_id"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer even that it's not the expected result, because admob sends you diferent kind of adverts depending on the size selected on xml, if I have size banner and size leaderboard, they'll get diferent adverts so it's better