# Receiving a normal AdMob banner after requesting a large one causes layout issues

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

1. Am requesting a LARGE Adsize AdMob Banner
2. I display it in its own FrameLayout container (which can also contain a separate warning if the user has an adblocker)
3. It works fine

[image: First Screenshot]

4. Except when AdMob can't find a large banner

[image]

In that case, the AdView takes the size of a large banner but only contains a smaller one.

How do I fix this? I can't use MAGIC banners because it will only display large banners on tablets, which is not the goal here.

Here's the layout file for the banner:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/admob_banner"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"/>
```

It is dynamically added to this grey container:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/material_grey_800"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <include
        layout="@layout/adblocker_banner"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Might be useful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327655/android-admob-size-on-dimensions-error-a-type-attribute-is-required-for-item

Comment: @Redman It's not. The adview has a LARGE_BANNER AdSize no matter what. But since the fillrate is not 99%, sometimes it falls back to standard banners. In that case, we have a standard (50dp height) banner inside of a large (100dp height) view.